# Why Taggit (Django-Tag) won't work once I used Tag.models.all()

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-taggit

I have implemented django-taggit successfully until I was trying to use the mixin to render the tags on a ListView of "PropertyListing" in this example:

The console keep telling me:

```
NameError: name 'Tag' is not defined
```

**The PROBLEM comes from the views.py line 4 apparently.

I cannot import "Tag" from the model like "PropertyListing" since its a third party library.

I have tried to import

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
```

in views.py but same error.

I am using django 2.1 and django-taggit 1.1.0

below is the code:

models.py

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager


class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)

    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cities'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PropertyListing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='property_listings')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Properties Listings'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(PropertyListing, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('core:property_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

views.py

```
class TagMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TagMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tags'] = Tag.objects.all()
        return context

class PropertyListingView(TagMixin, ListView):
    model = City
    model_type = PropertyImage
    queryset = PropertyListing.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'properties'
    template_name = 'core/property-listing.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PropertyListingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cities'] = City.objects.all()
        context['properties'] = PropertyImage.objects.select_related('image_property_listing')
        return context


class CityTaggedView(TagMixin, ListView):
    model = City
    context_object_name = 'cities'
    template_name = 'core/city-tagged.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return City.objects.filter(tags__slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
```

urls.py

```
path('', PropertyListingView.as_view(), name='property_listing'),
    path('tag/<slug:slug>/', CityTaggedView.as_view(), name='city_tagged')
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to **import the `Tag` model**, like:

```
# app/views.py

# import the Tag class
from taggit.models import Tag

class TagMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TagMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tags'] = Tag.objects.all()
        return context

# ...
```

After all, your code makes use of a `Tag`, but you never defined that in your `views.py` file. This has not much to do with Django, or taggit itself, it is just Python thaat does not understand what you mean with `Tag`.